# How can I calculate the grad of this higher dimensional matrix in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I got a simple example of using the autograd to do gradient descent using [this example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html#autograd) from the pytorch docs. Here's my simple working example:

```
s = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
#The "data"
x = torch.tensor(np.stack((s**2,s**3,s),axis=1), device=device, dtype=dtype)
v_coeffs = np.array([5,-2,4])
#The "target"
v = torch.tensor(np.expand_dims(v_coeffs[0]*s + v_coeffs[1]*s**2 + v_coeffs[2]*s**3,axis=1), device=device, dtype=dtype)
#The weights to determine
w = torch.randn(3, 1, device=device, dtype=dtype, requires_grad=True)
alpha = 10**-4

for t in range(t_range):
    vhat = x.mm(w)
    J = (v - vhat).pow(2).sum()
    J.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():

        w -= alpha*w.grad
        w.grad.zero_()
```

And it works. If I plot the values of w, I see that they approach the coefficients of the "target" v:

[convergence of weights picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8FTW.png)

For that example, x.shape = (100,3), v.shape = (100,1), w.shape = (3,1). So x.mm(w).shape = (100,1).

Now I'm trying to do the same thing but my matrix of weights has more dimensions: its shape is W.shape = (40,40,2). My X here will be a batch of (40,40,2) matrices, so it will have X.shape = (N,40,40,2).

Like my simple example above, I want to get a tensor of shape (N,1) by multiplying X*W. I can't figure out how to do it with a built in torch function; I've tried mm(), mul(), matmul(), and bmm(), and none of them seem to do what I want. Most of those throw errors relating to the sizes being different except mul(), but that gives back the same size tensor as X.

I tried to do it in this hack-y way, using list comprehension and doing it element-wise:

```
Q = torch.Tensor([torch.sum(x*W) for x in X])
```

but then it throws an error when I calculate J.backward() using Q:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

I don't know what this means, but I suspect it's because I did the list comp and now Q doesn't "know about" W and its requires_grad() being true. In the simple working example, vhat is directly calculated from w so it seems like J "knows" that w requires grad.

How can I do this?

edit: I figured out that I can do this:

```
Q = torch.sum(X.mul(W),dim=[1,2,3])
```

but it still seems like a workaround...

Comment: I am not sure myself but convert X and W to 2d, for eg. `W.view(1,-1)` and then do `mm()`?

Comment: As you suggest, I am not sure if a call to `Tensor` will propagate gradients. Have you tried replacing it with a call to `torch.stack()`?

Comment: In theano or tensorflow I would have accomplished this using `tensordot`, however there is apparently no direct equivalent in pytorch. The suggested workaround is quite similar to your last suggestion: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/tensordot-equivalent-in-pytorch/11809

Comment: @myrtlecat yeah, it seems like you need to "keep it in torch land". I have it working now with the code in my edit.